# How to add vertical scrollbar to react-bootstrap table body?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I want to add vertical scrollbar to react-bootstrap table body only and keep header sticky.

Sharing below Table structure it is not runnable:

```
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
    <div className={styles.tableFixHead}>
    <Table bordered hover data-testid="eligible-providers-table" id="eligible-providers-table">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </Table>
    <div>
```

CSS:

```
.tableFixHead {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 300px;
}



.tableFixHead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  // background: #eee;
}
```

I managed to achieve scrollbar by surrounding my table with div and added scrollbar to that div, kept table header fixed. It looks fine but I want scrollbar on table body.